# SharePoint List View Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, json-formatting, view-formatting

I want to check the date column in my list along with a flag to format list view:

I tried using AND and nested both don't seem to work:

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": 
       "=if([$DATE] <= @now+2592000000,if([$DateType]=='Expiry',
       'sp-field-severity-severeWarning',''),'')"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the format below:

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if(([$DATE] <= @now+2592000000)&&([$DateType]=='Expiry'),'sp-field-severity--severeWarning', '')"
}
```